# Change the shell of vim

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, vim

I change my shell to zsh now.But when I call shell in vim by `:! xxx` will call the bash.So, how can I call zsh in vim ?

Comment: How did you change the default shell? Vim picks `$SHELL` for running `:!` commands. See [`:h 'shell'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'shell')

Comment: Did you log out and in again after changing your shell?

Comment: I change by 'chsh',and it works for terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Inside vim, you can check your current shell by running

```
:set shell?
```

You can change the shell used in vim for the running session via command:

```
:set shell=/usr/bin/zsh
```

...And to make this change permanent, just put the set command in your vim RC file.

Comment: Yes, it works.But the completion of parameters by zsh don't works.Do you know this?

Comment: And some alias such as 'l' also don't works.